# Problem running intersect vector processing with line and polygon shapefiles

Tags: qgis, intersection

I have been trying to run intersect on two shapefiles, one is line, the other is polygon. Although processing appears to take place and a new shapefile is created and added, nothing is visible. I have checked their projections which are set the same.

Comment: How large are the two input files? Is the intersect actually completing? Shapefile creation to hold results is an earlier step. Is the shapefile actually empty (as in no records, not just they aren't visible)? Does an intersect actually occur between the two layers? Can you post a screenshot?